# Text in matrix does not fit in one line

Tags: equations, matrices, fit

I am trying to put variables in my document but it cannot fit in one row and goes somewhere out of the page... I tried some different things, like `\begin{split}` or `\begin{align}` or just `"\\"` but it doesn't seem to work... Any other ideas?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twoside=semi,usegeometry]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=.5cm,
  font=\Huge
]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\chapter{chapter}
\normalsize
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{equation}
 y = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 & 1 & \text{\text{if curve $c \in C$ applies cant size $k \in K$ and speed $s \in S$ and curve $c+1 \in C$ applies cant size $p \in K$ and speed $q \in S$}}\\  
 & 0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What you have posted is a code fragment, not a minimum working example.  But if I add the code needed for compilation, nothing falls outside the page.  So you have to provide more information, namely a working code example, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: `cases*` or `dcases*` from `mathtools`.

Comment: It's my thesis so it's kinda big document... Is it enough now?

Comment: Not enough: everything fits on the page.

Comment: How about now? :D

Answer (score 1):

[image: output of the following code]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twoside=semi,usegeometry]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=.5cm,
  font=\Huge
]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\chapter{chapter}
\normalsize
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{equation}
 y = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 & 1 & \text{\text{if curve $c \in C$ applies cant size $k \in K$ and speed $s \in S$ and curve $c+1 \in C$ applies cant size $p \in K$ and speed $q \in S$}}\\  
 & 0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 y = \left\{\begin{array}{lp{10cm}}
 1 & if curve $c \in C$ applies cant size $k \in K$ and speed $s \in S$ and curve $c+1 \in C$ applies cant size $p \in K$ and speed $q \in S$ \\  
 0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I put code in the comment?!

Comment: If you put 4 or more spaces at the beginning of any line, it should turn into a code block.

Comment: It does not... ;<
So, you mean to put it inside `\begin{equation}` ?

Comment: Thanks, it actually work in document but when I put it in code then everything else is getting red and it says that "Overfull \hbox detected in line xx"

Comment: If you comment out the \begin{equation} to \end{equation} in your code, do you still get the overfull hbox? What if you change p{10cm} to p{5cm} or something smaller than 10 centimeters?

Comment: I tried to change it to 5 or 3 but it's still red, like the whole document from the beginning till the `\end{equation}`

Comment: Have you tried commenting out that equation?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When something goes wrong in a TeX file, you can put a % sign in front of each line that you suspect causes the trouble. The % sign is a comment symbol, turning off the TeX code in that line. You can start by commenting out all of the lines in your file, putting a % in front of each one, for every line between \begin{document} and \end{document}. Then compile. Then delete one %, and compile again. Keep going until you find the error causing the redness.

Comment: So, putting % showed that error is placed in the line `1 & if curve $c \in C$ applies cant size $k \in K$ and speed $s \in S$ and curve $c+1 \in C$ applies cant size $p \in K$ and speed $q \in S$ \\ `